# Is this case statement unnecessary?

Tags: sql-server, case

I'm refactoring some code and came across this

```
WHERE CASE 
            WHEN (cast(ISNULL(datetimeColumn, '19990101') as date) >= '20160101') THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END = 1
```

This seems overly complicated to me.

Couldn't this be simply:

```
WHERE cast(ISNULL(datetimeColumn, '19990101') as date) >= '20160101'
```

Or even more simply:

```
WHERE ISNULL(datetimeColumn, '19990101') >= '20160101'
```

Comment: Yes, last one can be used.

Comment: You don't even need the `isnull()`, because `NULL` results in UNKNOWN in a comparison (which is not TRUE).

Comment: @HoneyBadger Yes, I noticed that a couple of minutes after posting the question.  The FUBARness of the original query had me so confused it took me a minute

Comment: Nor do you need the cast . To make things EXPLICTLY clear, you could compare your column to an **obvious** datetime** literal as `datetimecolumn >= '20160101 00:00:00'`

Answer (score 2):

You simply do :

```
WHERE datetimeColumn >= '20160101'
```